# Is there a way to write a Bash Script, that repeatedly keeps on running every X minutes?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm making calls to an API, which is constantly fetching me data. There is a limited number of calls that I can make per 15 mins. Can I automate the whole process, and keep the script running for like 24 hours, which executes a certain command at the interval of 15 mins?

Comment: `cron` is often used on the command line to schedule tasks at regular intervals like the one you’re describing.

Comment: When X is a convenient fraction of an hour like 'every 15 minutes', `cron` is very suitable.  When X is an inconvenient fraction of an hour, like 'every 7 minutes', then you might think about using `at` instead of `cron`. You'd have an `at` job which (a) runs the real script separately and (b) schedules itself to run again in X minutes (`at now + X minutes`). This could be subject to slow drift as there is a possibility of a short delay between when the job was intended to run and when it reschedules itself. You'll have to decide whether that matters. You could schedule the next intended time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
while(true)
   do
   # write your bash command to fetch API response using GET api_endpoint_url
   sleep 15m
   done
```

I hope this might serve the purpose!

Answer (score 2):

Usual alternatives:

a) use "cron" to trigger the script periodically.

b) finish the script with one "at" command, to reschedule it.

c) a never ending loop, as the loop in @VikasYadav answer. However, this solution has the problem of stop working after system restart or script crash. It should be complete with some "keep alive" configuration (/etc/inittab or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your crontab with the following command:

```
# crontab -e
```

Add the following line at the end of crontab:

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/your/command.sh
```

That will run your command every 15 minutes.